# How can I keep my 3 month old leopard gecko warm

Tags: reptiles, geckos, terrariums, temperature, heaters

I have a baby leopard gecko but my heat lamp just broke and I will have no money for a new one for about a week or two how can I keep her warm until then?? Is a floor vent heater okay? I’m panicking about this because I do not want her to pass away. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

A few options at hand:

1) Increase the temperature of your room, can use your regular home heating system, space heaters (do not use unsupervised) etc..

2) Use hot water bottles (wrapped in a towel to prevent thermal burns)

3) Place tank in a room with lots of natural sunlight beaming through the windows, you can try to place part of the tank in direct sunlight but be cautious as there may be a chance for the tank to overheat.

4) Your body heat, can have him in contact with you when you are home.

5) Heatpacks or handwarmers at a sporting goods store, place these UNDER the tank.

6) Ask a local reptile group if someone can sell or lend you a light for cheap, check with the local SPCA if they can house your reptile until you get a new heat source.

7) Check with friends and family to see if they can lend you money to buy a light.

It is important to not feed your reptile during this time as they need heat to digest their food.

Answer (score 3):

You might try some of the 40-hour heat packs used for shipping reptiles, which you can get in a pet store or online; you would still have to buy it, but they are not very expensive.  Using a floor vent heater in the room is a good idea if the house is cold, but it's a dangerous and tricky game to have it blow right on the tank as a primary heat source-- there is a very good chance you could over- or under heat your gecko.

Answer (score -3):

I put my oven on warm which is 170 degrees and then set him in the temporary cardboard box carrier (out of the habitat) on the stove.  It vents the oven so it was super toasty back there in the middle of the stove, but cooler on the outside so he could move sides of the box if needed.  Obviously this was just for two days till I could get another heater obviously you are not supposed to leave your oven on like that either.  But it worked.  he was toasty and seemed happy.  I put some papertowels in there with him so he would feel secure.

Comment: Seriously? How warm does a gecko's environment need to be? Do you have any links that suggest the low-temp oven is safe for them?

Comment: it is 76C are you making dinner? i do not think any living thing can survive this temparature.